# authorize.net mac API

Tags: macos, authorize.net

I have built a kiosk environment in MAC OSX 10.6.6 and i wanto charge a PC user before he starts using the system. i have the application made. I wanto use authorize.net for authenticating. With what i have searched, CIM SOAP is the method i should use.

My question is is there any webservice available on authorize.net where i can send a xml file and expect a response .? If not, what other options do i have??

thanks in advance. If any sample code or reference is there, let me know( FOR MAC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorize.Net's API is platform agnostic so it doesn't matter what environment you use it in. It can be a Mac, PC, POS system, or website, etc.

Their [AIM API has an XML interface](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/News-and-Announcements/New-XML-API-for-Transaction-Processing/td-p/6402) for processing transactions. You can get a [developer's account](http://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/) to test your integration with. They also offer [sample code](http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/samplecode/) to get you started.